# MIVA API Created DLL wont register when Compiling

Tags: c++, api, dll, miva

I code in Miva Script daily. I recently got some API information and am trying to write my own custom functions for Miva in C++. I was able to build a DLL for one custom function but i am having an issue with the compiler. It is flagging an Unknown error 193 "Unable to register .dll/.so C:\Msc\Builtins\Mydll.dll" This functionality would be of great use to me as i have huge function files. If anyone has any experience with this any help whatsoever would be Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Did you build your DLL with the right 'bitness' (32 / 64 bit)?

Comment: Yes i built it 32 bit. Everything in VStudio was set for x86.

Comment: Is that what Miva wants?  Did you try building as 64 bit?

Comment: Miva supports both 64bit and 32 bitness. Here we run a server with Miva Empressa in 32 bit. In our test environment we can run either but we still run 32bit versions to simply stay the same as the server. From more information i got yesterday i believe this is miva compiler specific. I was hoping to find someone that has written custom functions for Miva. They are huge in the shopping cart biz, but using the scripting language like we do is not very popular. Its difficult to find people who have experience with it. Thank you Paul for your help.